# Unable to display a reusable select input(dropdown) component in Angular form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to implement select-input(dropdown) component in **Angular** register form.
Here is the implementation of my reusable select-input component:

***select-input.component.ts***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-input',
  templateUrl: './select-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-input.component.css']
})
export class SelectInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor 
{
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() options: {value: number; description: string}[];
  
  constructor() { }

  writeValue(obj: any): void
  {
    
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void
  {
    
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void
  {
    
  }
}
```

***select-input.component.html***

```
<div>
    <label for={{name}} style="margin-right: 2px;">{{label}}:</label>
    <select name={{name}}>
        <options *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
            {{option.description}}
        </options>
    </select>
</div>
```

***register.component.ts***

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit 
{
  countries: {value: number, description: string}[] = [
    {value: 0, description: 'Canada'},
    {value: 1, description: 'USA'},
    {value: 2, description: 'England'},
    {value: 3, description: 'Japan'},
  ]
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    this.initializeForm();
  }
  
  initializeForm()
  {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      country: [this.countries]
    })
    
  }
}
```

***register.component.html***

```
<select-input [formControl]='registerForm.controls["country"]' ngDefaultControl
        [label]='"Country"' [name]='"countries"' [options]="countries">
</select-input>
```

When i run the application i see the empty dropdown element but when i check the html i see the values in options element like the image below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake is in **select-input.component.html** -
`<options>` need to changes to `<option>`

```
<div>
    <label for={{name}} style="margin-right: 2px;">{{label}}:</label>
    <select name={{name}}>
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{option.description}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: You are right mate!! Thanks for the correction